# Format dates in response field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, range-query

My server on which the application runs (uses ES) and ES are in central american time and I am accessing it from my server which is in IST.

I want some charts and data for today(Say Jan 3) so I send `from date` as today 12:00 AM to `to date` as current date in UTC to date range query. I get accurate number of records but I want the date to be shown as todays date alone(Jan 3), It gets divided between today(Jan 3) and yesterday(Jan 2) on client side access - ideally it should only todays date on client side for all records. Kibana renders correctly. So obviously there is a way and I am missing someting

I am using date range query - passing UTC for both to and from date and timezone offset as well.

Also, I am querying on a field which is of default type Date.I have not specified any custom date formats

Can somebody pleas help me with this?

Comment: What client are you using? It would help to know how you are accessing the data.

Comment: Browser, I am accessing the application from my laptop using chrome.

Comment: OK, but are you calling elastic search directly from your browser? Or is your browser calling a server that is getting its data from ES, rendering a page and then returning that to your browser?

Comment: browser is calling a server that is getting its data from ES, rendering a page and then returning that to your browser, both the server and ES are in the same timezone.

Comment: Thanks - and is the server code yours? You wrote the server code?

Comment: Yes. It is mine

Comment: Have solved it using date histogram bucketing using timezone. Range query timezone is used as part of querying not for response formation.